# How do I re order my plot into a descending order when plotting a single column in factor form?

Tags: r

My df looks like this:

```
Department_lower:
beverage
entree
salad
salad
giftcards
```

Depart_lower is set as factor. We are looking at number of occurrences.
`plot(df$Department_lower)`
Yields
Effective plot but not in descending order. How to arrange descending?
[image]

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your data using `head(dput(df), 30)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Reorder your data: `df[order(df$Department_lower,decreasing = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost sure you used `barplot`, just `sort` the `table`.

```
barplot(sort(table(dat$dep_lower), decreasing=TRUE))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(216048)
dat <- data.frame(dep_lower=sample(c('beverage', 'entree', 'salad', 'giftcards'),
       50, replace=TRUE))
```